# Total Contract Value Field in Opportunity

Tags: opportunity

I have a field label "Total Contract Value" in every opportunity. What I want to know is if this is a custom field or built into Salesforce?

Here's a snippet of it.

[image]

It automatically gets its value from the attached products of the same opportunity.

For example, if I have 2 "Test Products" that are $50 each, the Total Contract Value is set to $100 automatically.

How can I change this functionality? I can not find this field anywhere in the Setup.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you check in Rename Tabs and Labels option in setup? Looking at the functionality it will be Amount field of Opportunity and its label has been overridden.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. There doesn't seem to be any trace of the "Amount" field or the "Total Contract Value" field in that area.

Comment: Can you also check under Setup--> Opportunity --> Fields --> Custom Fields ?

Comment: That was the first place I checked! For some reason I can not see it there! I only see "Total Monthly Cost" and "Total Monthly Revenue".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I've found that the "Total Contract Value" field is actually the "Amount" field. I'm not sure how the name got changed, but at least I know it's not a custom field.

I thought it would be a formula field but instead it is a currency field. I didn't know those fields could do calculation. Anywho, that's another topic.